# WebLogic: URL mapping doesn't work

Tags: java, jsp, weblogic

I have several JSPs and a URL mapped to each in web.xml.  The links at the bottom starting with `<servlet-name>7770015020</servlet-name>` don't work in the browser (there's a comment right before it that says "OTHER FEEDS".  However, if I move that servlet definition and mapping to the top, then it's reachable in the browser.  Am I reaching some limit here?  I don't get an error when I deploy the war in WebLogic.  The other links at the top work.

```
<web-app>
    <description>JSP Test MOCK</description>

    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->
    <!-- <servlet> <servlet-name>test</servlet-name> <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/test.jsp</jsp-file> 
        <init-param> <param-name>hello</param-name> <param-value>test</param-value> 
        </init-param> </servlet> <servlet-mapping> <servlet-name>test</servlet-name> 
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/test1</url-pattern> 
        </servlet-mapping> <servlet-mapping> <servlet-name>test</servlet-name> <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/test2/*</url-pattern> 
        </servlet-mapping> -->
    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->



    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->
    <!-- ******** TEST GOOD FEED ************* -->
    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->
    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->



    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/feed.jsp</jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/benefits/integratedCare/careCoordinatorProfiles
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->
    <!-- ******** TEST GOOD LINKS ************* -->
    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-good_subjectdoc_absoluteurl_samebase_singledocname.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/good_subjectdoc_absoluteurl_samebase_singledocname.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-good_subjectdoc_absoluteurl_samebase_singledocname.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/good_subjectdoc_absoluteurl_samebase_singledocname.xml
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-good_subjectdoc_relativeurl_noext
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/good_subjectdoc_absoluteurl_samebase_singledocname.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-good_subjectdoc_relativeurl_noext
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/good_subjectdoc_relativeurl_noext
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-good_subjectdoc_docname_noext
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/good_subjectdoc_absoluteurl_samebase_singledocname.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-good_subjectdoc_docname_noext</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/good_subjectdoc_docname_noext
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-good_subjectdoc_folder_endslash
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/good_subjectdoc_absoluteurl_samebase_singledocname.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-good_subjectdoc_folder_endslash
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/good_subjectdoc_folder_endslash/*
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-good_subjectdoc_extrafolders_docname_ext.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/good_subjectdoc_absoluteurl_samebase_singledocname.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-good_subjectdoc_extrafolders_docname_ext.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/x/y/z/good_subjectdoc_extrafolders_docname_ext.xml
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-good_subjectdoc_extrafolders_docname_noext
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/good_subjectdoc_absoluteurl_samebase_singledocname.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-good_subjectdoc_extrafolders_docname_noext
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/x/y/z/good_subjectdoc_extrafolders_docname_noext
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-good_subjectdoc_extrafolders_folder_endslash
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/good_subjectdoc_absoluteurl_samebase_singledocname.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-good_subjectdoc_extrafolders_folder_endslash
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/x/y/z/good_subjectdoc_extrafolders_folder_endslash/*
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-good_subjectddoc_absoluteurl_pathdifferentfrombase.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/good_subjectdoc_absoluteurl_samebase_singledocname.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-good_subjectddoc_absoluteurl_pathdifferentfrombase.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/testnewpath/good_subjectddoc_absoluteurl_pathdifferentfrombase.xml
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-good_subjectdoc_nocharset_in_httpheaders.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/good_subjectdoc_nocharset_in_httpheaders.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-good_subjectdoc_nocharset_in_httpheaders.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/good_subjectdoc_nocharset_in_httpheaders.xml
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->

    <!-- ******** TEST BAD LINKS ************* -->
    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_bad_relativelink_startatAA.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/good_subjectdoc_absoluteurl_samebase_singledocname.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_bad_relativelink_startatAA.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/ERROR_bad_relativelink_startatAA.xml
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- ***********************************************`*********************** -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_404_error_subjectdoc_nohtmlerrorpage.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/ERROR_404_error_subjectdoc_nohtmlerrorpage.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_404_error_subjectdoc_nohtmlerrorpage.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/ERROR_404_error_subjectdoc_nohtmlerrorpage.xml
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_407_subjectdoc_textheader_error_onprintlntext.html
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/ERROR_407_subjectdoc_textheader_error_onprintlntext.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_407_subjectdoc_textheader_error_onprintlntext.html
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/ERROR_407_subjectdoc_textheader_error_onprintlntext.html
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_500_subjectdoc_htmlheader_error_realhtmlerrorpage.html
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/ERROR_500_subjectdoc_htmlheader_error_realhtmlerrorpage.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_500_subjectdoc_htmlheader_error_realhtmlerrorpage.html
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/ERROR_500_subjectdoc_htmlheader_error_realhtmlerrorpage.html
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_500_subjectdoc_xmlheader_xmlsubjectdoc.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/ERROR_500_subjectdoc_xmlheader_xmlsubjectdoc.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_500_subjectdoc_xmlheader_xmlsubjectdoc.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/ERROR_500_subjectdoc_xmlheader_xmlsubjectdoc.xml
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_404_subjectdoc_xmlheader_error_onjspxmlpage.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/ERROR_404_subjectdoc_xmlheader_error_onjspxmlpage.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_404_subjectdoc_xmlheader_error_onjspxmlpage.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/ERROR_404_subjectdoc_xmlheader_error_onjspxmlpage.xml
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_200_subjectdoc_htmlheader_error_jspredirect_toerrorjsphtml.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/ERROR_200_subjectdoc_htmlheader_error_jspredirect_toerrorjsphtml.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_200_subjectdoc_htmlheader_error_jspredirect_toerrorjsphtml.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/ERROR_200_subjectdoc_htmlheader_error_jspredirect_toerrorjsphtml.xml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- ********** REDIRECT TO THIS ACTUAL HTML ERROR PAGE ******** -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_200_subjectdoc_htmlheader_error_weblogicredirect_toerrorjsphtml_ACTUALERRORPAGE.jsp
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/ERROR_200_subjectdoc_htmlheader_error_weblogicredirect_toerrorjsphtml_ACTUALERRORPAGE.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>
            7770015010-ERROR_200_subjectdoc_htmlheader_error_weblogicredirect_toerrorjsphtml_ACTUALERRORPAGE.jsp
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/ERROR_200_subjectdoc_htmlheader_error_weblogicredirect_toerrorjsphtml_ACTUALERRORPAGE.jsp
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_500_subjectdoc_htmlheader_error_jspredirect_toerror_500html.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/ERROR_500_subjectdoc_htmlheader_error_jspredirect_toerror_500html.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_500_subjectdoc_htmlheader_error_jspredirect_toerror_500html.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/ERROR_500_subjectdoc_htmlheader_error_jspredirect_toerror_500html.xml
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- ********** REDIRECT TO THIS ACTUAL HTML ERROR PAGE ******** -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_500_subjectdoc_htmlheader_error_jspredirect_toerror_500html_ACTUALERRORPAGE.jsp
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/ERROR_500_subjectdoc_htmlheader_error_jspredirect_toerror_500html_ACTUALERRORPAGE.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_500_subjectdoc_htmlheader_error_jspredirect_toerror_500html_ACTUALERRORPAGE.jsp
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/ERROR_500_subjectdoc_htmlheader_error_jspredirect_toerror_500html_ACTUALERRORPAGE.jsp
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_404_subjectdoc_htmlheader_error_weblogicredirect_toerrorjsphtml.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/ERROR_404_subjectdoc_htmlheader_error_weblogicredirect_toerrorjsphtml.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <!-- Define an error handler for 404 pages -->
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_404_subjectdoc_htmlheader_error_weblogicredirect_toerrorjsphtml.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/doesntexist.xml
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_407_validfeedcontent.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/ERROR_407_validfeedcontent.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_407_validfeedcontent.xml</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/ERROR_407_validfeedcontent.xml
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_malformed_xml_subjectdoc.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/ERROR_malformed_xml_subjectdoc.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_malformed_xml_subjectdoc.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/ERROR_malformed_xml_subjectdoc.xml
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_nonxml_html_subjectdoc_htmlheader.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/ERROR_nonxml_html_subjectdoc_htmlheader.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_nonxml_html_subjectdoc_htmlheader.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/ERROR_nonxml_html_subjectdoc_htmlheader.xml
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_differentxml_subjectdoc_xmlheader.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/ERROR_differentxml_subjectdoc_xmlheader.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_differentxml_subjectdoc_xmlheader.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/ERROR_differentxml_subjectdoc_xmlheader.xml
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_validsubjecdoc_badheadercontenttype.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/ERROR_validsubjecdoc_badheadercontenttype.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_validsubjecdoc_badheadercontenttype.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/ERROR_validsubjecdoc_badheadercontenttype.xml
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_nodata_onsubjectdoc_goodheader_goodheader.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/ERROR_nodata_onsubjectdoc_goodheader_goodheader.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_nodata_onsubjectdoc_goodheader_goodheader.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/ERROR_nodata_onsubjectdoc_goodheader_goodheader.xml
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_nosubjectdoc_feed_dasextensiononly_errors.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/ERROR_nosubjectdoc_feed_dasextensiononly_errors.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_nosubjectdoc_feed_dasextensiononly_errors.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/ERROR_nosubjectdoc_feed_dasextensiononly_errors.xml
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_pointtonoserver_noheaders.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/ERROR_pointtonoserver_noheaders.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_pointtonoserver_noheaders.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/ERROR_pointtonoserver_noheaders.xml
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_pointtoserver_behindfirewall_noheaders
        </servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015010/ERROR_pointtoserver_behindfirewall_noheaders.jsp
        </jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015010-ERROR_pointtoserver_behindfirewall_noheaders.xml
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015010/path/path2/ERROR_pointtoserver_behindfirewall_noheaders.xml
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- ******************** OTHER FEEDS ************************************************** -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015020</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015020/feed.jsp</jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015020</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015020/benefits/integratedCare/careCoordinatorProfiles
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- ********************************************************************** -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>7770015030</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/7770015030/feed.jsp</jsp-file>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hello</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>7770015030</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/2.16.840.1.113883.3.42.10001.100001.12/7770015030/benefits/integratedCare/careCoordinatorProfiles
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    ...{DELETED}
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about why it doesn't work in the way you have written (it seems likely that you are in deed hitting some kind of limit), but there's a built in JSP servlet that you could map to the root context, and then just name your JSPs in a manner consistent with the desired path.  If that's not flexible enough, write your own servlet, map that to the root context, write logic to map everything in whatever way you desire, and simply instantiate and invoke the JspServlet in code.

What version of Weblogic are you using?  Have you tried updating?  Is it possible that you have a subtle syntax error in one of your mappings and that it and any mappings that fall after it aren't loading?